# Transform Dataframe Using Dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, tidyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
      Gene        SNP  Score
1     AKT3  rs2220276 6.5091
2 ARHGAP44  rs2220276 4.7194
3   BRINP2 rs16851037 3.2606
4 C12orf42 rs16851037 3.2563
5  CCDC122 rs11619756 4.3142
6   CCDC68 rs11619756 2.3614
```

I want to transform the dataframe so it looks like this - essentially creating an extra column for each element in the `Gene` column that matches the `SNP` column.

```
   Gene 1         SNP  Gene 1 Score       Gene 2   Gene 2 Score      
1     AKT3  rs2220276        6.5091     ARHGAP44         4.7194 
2   BRINP2 rs16851037        3.2606     C12orf42         3.2563
5  CCDC122 rs11619756        4.3142       CCDC68         2.3614
```

How can I achieve this?

```
df <- data.frame(Gene = c("AKT3", "ARHGAP44", "BRINP2", "C12orf42", "CCDC122","CCDC68")  , 
           "SNP" = c("rs2220276", "rs2220276", "rs16851037", "rs16851037","rs11619756", "rs11619756"),
           Score = c(6.5091, 4.7194, 3.2606, 3.2563, 4.3142, 2.3614))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transform this by using `pivot_wider()` from `tidyr` package, assisted by a helper column, `id`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(SNP) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  pivot_wider(id_cols=SNP, names_from = id, values_from = c(Gene, Score))
```

Output:

```
  SNP        Gene_1  Gene_2   Score_1 Score_2
  <chr>      <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1 rs2220276  AKT3    ARHGAP44    6.51    4.72
2 rs16851037 BRINP2  C12orf42    3.26    3.26
3 rs11619756 CCDC122 CCDC68      4.31    2.36
```

Answer (score 1):

The data is already in a favorable shape.

Anyways, the desired format can be generated using `pivot_wider` and `unnest_wider`

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(df, SNP, values_from=c(Score, Gene), values_fn=list) |> 
  unnest_wider(Score_, names_sep="") |> 
  unnest_wider(Gene_, names_sep="")
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  SNP        Score_1 Score_2 Gene_1  Gene_2
  <chr>        <dbl>   <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
1 rs2220276     6.51    4.72 AKT3    ARHGAP44
2 rs16851037    3.26    3.26 BRINP2  C12orf42
3 rs11619756    4.31    2.36 CCDC122 CCDC68
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you always want to keep the first occurrence of any duplicate you can do

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  distinct(SNP, .keep_all = TRUE)

     Gene        SNP  Score
1    AKT3  rs2220276 6.5091
2  BRINP2 rs16851037 3.2606
3 CCDC122 rs11619756 4.3142
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dcast`

```
library(data.table)
dcast(setDT(df), SNP ~ rowid(SNP), value.var = c("Gene", "Score"))
Key: <SNP>
          SNP  Gene_1   Gene_2 Score_1 Score_2
       <char>  <char>   <char>   <num>   <num>
1: rs11619756 CCDC122   CCDC68  4.3142  2.3614
2: rs16851037  BRINP2 C12orf42  3.2606  3.2563
3:  rs2220276    AKT3 ARHGAP44  6.5091  4.7194
```

---

Or similar option with `pivot_wider`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(rn = rowid(SNP)) %>% 
   pivot_wider(names_from = rn, values_from = c(Gene, Score))
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  SNP        Gene_1  Gene_2   Score_1 Score_2
  <chr>      <chr>   <chr>      <dbl>   <dbl>
1 rs2220276  AKT3    ARHGAP44    6.51    4.72
2 rs16851037 BRINP2  C12orf42    3.26    3.26
3 rs11619756 CCDC122 CCDC68      4.31    2.36
```